# I want to add new row in table and with sheet protect

Tags: excel, vba

**What I want the code to do:** On change event, Only insert a new row if we are on the last row.

**What the code actually does:** It inserts a new row on any change, no matter if we are on the last row or not.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As ListRow
    Static flag As Boolean
    
    ' Unprotect the sheet
    Me.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword" ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password
    
    On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily
    Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("Table1") ' Replace "Table1" with the name of your table
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Restore normal error handling
    
    ' Check if the table exists and the sheet is unprotected
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        Set lastRow = tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count)
        
        ' Check if the last row is the target and is filled; if filled, set flag to prevent further additions
        If Target.Row = lastRow.Range.Row + 1 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(lastRow.Range) > 0 Then
            flag = True ' Set flag to indicate table is full
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not flag Then ' Proceed only if the table isn't full
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent infinite loop
        
        ' Unprotect the sheet to allow row addition
        Me.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword" ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password
        
        ' Add a new row to the table
        Set lastRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        
        ' Protect the sheet again
        Me.Protect Password:="YourPassword" ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Enable events
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use `Dim flag As Boolean` instead of `Static`
- The condition for `write in last row` is `Target.Row = lastRow.Range.Row`
- `If flag Then` add a new row when `flag = True`
- btw,
  I don't understand how the sheet protection logic works in your code. Excel raises an error before triggering the Change event if users attempt to modify a protected sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As ListRow
    Dim flag As Boolean  ' **
    ' Unprotect the sheet
'    Me.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword" ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password
    On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily
    Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("Table1") ' Replace "Table1" with the name of your table
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Restore normal error handling
    ' Check if the table exists and the sheet is unprotected
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        Set lastRow = tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count)
        ' Check if the last row is the target and is filled; if filled, set flag to prevent further additions
          ' **
        If Target.Row = lastRow.Range.Row And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(lastRow.Range) > 0 Then
            flag = True ' Set flag to indicate table is full
        End If
    End If
    If flag Then  ' ** ' Proceed only if the table isn't full
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent infinite loop
        ' Unprotect the sheet to allow row addition
'        Me.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword" ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password
        ' Add a new row to the table
        Set lastRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        ' Protect the sheet again
'        Me.Protect Password:="YourPassword" ' Replace "YourPassword" with the actual password
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Enable events
    End If
End Sub
```